# File data gets erased while loading through pickle

Tags: python

Ive created a class called Animals to create animal like objects and when i create the objects and save it to a file called animals.txt using pickle module it works perfectly fine but when i try to load it from another python file i get an error saying that "EOFError: Ran out of input" and after that the whole data on that file gets completely erased. I dont understand why is this happening. Maybe because the file size might be large enough for the pickle to handle.

```
from pickle import *
fo=open(animals.txt,"wb+")
List = []
try:
     fo1=tuple (load (fo))
     List .append (fo1)
except EOFError:
     pass
class Animal:
     def __init__(self, age, name,, owner, speed)
           self.age=age
           self.name =name
           self.owner=owner
           self.speed=speed
    def diplay_attr (self):
          return 'age = {0}, name={1}, owner={2}, speed =
          {3} ' .format(self.age,self.name,self.owner,self.speed)

#creating objects
Dog = Animal (10, 'Tommy', 'bill', '6ft', '15mph')
Cat = Animal (3, 'perry', 'kevin', '2ft', '12mph')
D = Dog.display_attr ()
C = Cat.display_attr


#saving everything to the list
List.append (tuple (D))
List.append (tuple (C))

#dumping List contents to the file
dump (List,fo)
fo.close ()
```

Now if i load the file contents from another python file as i said the whole data on the file gets erased

This is the code ive used to load the file

```
from pickle import *
List =[]
with open('robots.txt','wb+') as fo:
      fo2=tuple (load (fo))
      List.append (fo2)
print (List)
```

When executed got an error as

```
fo2 = tuple (load (fo))
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Thankyou. Any help is appreciated

EDIT :Sorry I didn't realize that i had typed this instead of self but in the actuall code ive used self and here everything goes just fine but the problem persists only while loading the file

Comment: You are using `this` instead of `self`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are reading from the .txt file you created, you should open it with 'rb', to only have reading abilities.

Also, please check your code for mistakes before posting, there are lots in the first code segment you posted.

Comment: I know,thankyou, I am just a new one to this community

Answer (score 0):

You are using `'wb+'` mode to open your file, which means that it automatically overwrites the existing file. It has nothing to do with loading it from another file. You should use `'rb+'` if you want to read and write, or just `'rb'` if you only want to read. See [this page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm) for more on file modes.